# Is there anything in mariadb to import data from .txt file or different format where i can define a filed value length from position to position?

Tags: mysql, datetime, mariadb, load-data-infile, importdata

Trying to import the data in maridadb and my data will look like

"20220910SATURDAY"
"20220911MON"
"20220912TUE"
"20220913THUR"

represents the data.
My database structured columns are :
column1:Year,
column2:Month,
Column3:Day,
Column4:DayInLetters.
Need to define a configuration like in every line first 4 letters i.e from 0 to 3 is year field ,
4-5 is Mon,
6-7 is Day,
8-last is DayInLetters.
Is there any solution?

Comment: That is bad design: 1 column defined as date is enough, so you can retrieve information with YEAR(), MONTH(),DAY() and DAYNAME() functions to get the values.

Comment: @GeorgRichter, that is not the actual data. That is the sample data

Answer (score 0):

This is a job for [LOAD DATA INFILE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html). Because the fields in your input file are not delimited by commas, tabs, or similar you need to use an uncommon feature called [input preprocessing](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html#load-data-input-preprocessing).

Giving this SQL statement to a command-line mysql client will work.

```sql
LOAD DATA INFILE '/tmp/data.txt' INTO TABLE tbl (@line)
      SET year =           SUBSTRING(@line, 1, 4),
          month =          SUBSTRING(@line, 5, 2),
          day =            SUBSTRING(@line, 7, 2),
          day_in_letters = SUBSTRING(@line, 9);
```

This loads each row in turn of the named file into a temporary variable `@line`, then extracts a [substring](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring) for each column.

But, **Pro tip**, it is far better data design practice to put calendar dates into [DATE columns (or TIMESTAMP or DATETIME columns)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/datetime.html) rather than designing your own way of representing calendar dates. MariaDB and MySQL have comprehensive and completely debugged [date-arithmetic features](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html).

Comment: instead of writing a query above is there any other solution like defining all the field positions in one file . 
And the follow-up question is this is just one of the format and we do have many different formats like 
HEAD>>>
DATA
TRAIL
And we need to read only the data